# How does Spark CrossValidator determine how to apply the grid parameters

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

The following snippet from the Spark docs for `ML Tuning`  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-tuning.html apparently sets up the `numFeatures` for a `Hashing TermFrequency`  and `regParam` (regularization) for a `LogisticRegression` model:

The `HashingTF` and `LogisticRegression`:

```
val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
  .setInputCol(tokenizer.getOutputCol)
  .setOutputCol("features")
val lr = new LogisticRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
```

The **ParamGridBuilder** for the `CrossValidator` :

```
// We use a ParamGridBuilder to construct a grid of parameters to search over.
// With 3 values for hashingTF.numFeatures and 2 values for lr.regParam,
// this grid will have 3 x 2 = 6 parameter settings for CrossValidator to choose from.
val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
  .addGrid(hashingTF.numFeatures, Array(10, 100, 1000))
  .addGrid(lr.regParam, Array(0.1, 0.01))
  .build()
```

How does the `CrossValidator` "know" how to apply the grid values to the respective entities? I was looking to see if it were by reflection but that were not clear .

The methods that are likely being *set* by the `CrossValidator are:

**HashingTF**:

```
  /** @group setParam */
  @Since("1.2.0")
  def setNumFeatures(value: Int): this.type = set(numFeatures, value)
```

**LogisticRegression**:

```
class LogisticRegressionModel @Since("1.3.0") (
 ..
 @Since("1.3.0") val numFeatures: Int,
```

And here is the invocation on the `CrossValidator`:

```
val cv = new CrossValidator()
  .setEstimator(pipeline)
  .setEvaluator(new BinaryClassificationEvaluator)
  .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
  .setNumFolds(2)  // Use 3+ in practice
```

I was not able to determine how the `setEstimatorParamMaps` results in properly setting the `HashingTF` and `LogisticRegression` values. (Note this *does* work!)

The reason for this question is I want to add a new `Evaluator` and am uncertain how to match that up with the `CrossValidator` capabilities.

A specific example: for `LDAModel`: we have tuning parameters `k`, `vocabSize`, and `docConcentration` : how should the `ParamGrid` be set up for those?

Comment: @user8371915  Oh I better understand your comment - and you're incorrect: the above code *does* work - it's in the linked Spark documentation. I was asking **how** is it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A specific example: for LDAModel: we have tuning parameters k, vocabSize, and docConcentration : how should the ParamGrid be set up for those?

`addGrid` takes a `Param` and `Array` of compatible values. Typically it is set on `Estimator` (`LDA`) not `Transformer (`LDAModel`).

To set `k`, `docConcentration` just follow the types:

```
val lda = new LDA()

val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
 .addGrid(lda.k, Array(3, 5, 7))
 .addGrid(lda.docConcentration, Array(Array(0.1, 0.4, 0.5)))
 .build()
```

> we have tuning parameters (...) vocabSize

Vocab size is defined by the input vector. It is cannot be tuned.

> How does the CrossValidator "know" how to apply the grid values to the respective entities?

Models provide `fit` method which takes `dataset` and `ParamMap`. [For example `LDA`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.LDA@fit(dataset:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5B_%5D,paramMap:org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap):M):

> ```
> def fit(dataset: Dataset[_], paramMap: ParamMap): LDAModel
> ```
>
> Fits a single model to the input data with provided parameter map.

This variant [is used](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/774398045b7b0cde4afb3f3c1a19ad491cf71ed1/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/tuning/CrossValidator.scala#L152) by `CrossValidator`.